# Typescript can't use animateMotion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, svg-animate

Typescript complains when I try to use `animateMotion` inside a React component.

`Property 'animateMotion' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.`

`Property 'mpath' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.`

### Code

```
import * as React from 'react'

type OrbitProps = {
  duration: number;
  radius: number;
}

export const Orbit: React.FunctionComponent<OrbitProps>= ({duration, radius}) => {
  const cx = 50
  const cy = 50
  return (
      <g>
        <path
          d={`M ${cx}, ${cy}
          m -${radius}, 0
          a ${radius},${radius} 0 1,0 ${radius*2},0
          a ${radius},${radius} 0 1,0 -${radius*2},0`}
          id="ellipse1"
        />
        <circle r="3">
          <animateMotion dur={`${duration}s`} repeatCount="indefinite">
            <mpath xlinkHref="#ellipse1" />
          </animateMotion>
        </circle>
      </g>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

```
declare namespace JSX { 
  interface IntrinsicElements { 
    "animateMotion": any,
    "mpath": any, 
  } 
}
```

Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

Comment: Already tried, and it doesn't work and it's a "native" SVG element, so it's suposed to be lowercase just like any other `div`, `svg`, `g` or whatever.

Comment: Can  you try this; `declare namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            "animateMotion": any,
            "mpath": any,
        }
    }`

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Add as it's own response or edit this one and I will accept it :)

Comment: No problem and i edited my answer. Maybe it can help someone else  :)

Comment: @sdkcy Would you mind taking a minute to explain how `declare namespace JSX` works? Tried searching for docs and didn't find any.

Comment: Thanks @sdkcy! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `npm install @types/react --save`?

Comment: Yes.

    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.3.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.5",

Comment: Not that this helps, but I don't think `@types/react` supports `animateMotion` and `mpath`. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L2483 Trying to find a patch.